# Método retorna dados diferentes conforme a arquitetura do android

Tags: android, c, biblioteca, android-ndk, arm

Eu criei uma biblioteca para Android e que tem um método que retorna os milissegundos da data epoch. Testei em 2 arquiteturas diferentes para validar se os retornos estavam corretos.

- armeabi-v7a: **Retorna um número negativo diferente do epoch**
- arm64-v8a: **Retorna corretamente**

Verifique se os tipos dos dados poderiam estar influenciando os retornos e tentei retornar com long long e tive o mesmo problema.
Estou utilizando o clang (llvm) para o cross compile e estou passando os parametros de compilação conforme o [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) e [ABI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#v7a) do Android.

**Parâmetros de compilação**

```
 -target thumbv7-linux-androideabi -march=armv7-a 
 -mthumb -mfpu=vfpv4-d16 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfpu=neon -msoft-float
```

**Método**

```
#include <sys/time.h>

long getTime(){
  struct timeval tp;
  gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
  //Calcula os milisegundos da data epoch
  long ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
  return ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após algumas tentativas e erros, identifiquei que era o tipo das variáveis e o cálculo para os milissegundos.
Pelo que consegui entender na hora que o compilador montava o meu bloco de código ele estava utilizando os tipos primitivos errados `long ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;` nesse ponto do código.

Tentei manter a estrutura inicial alterando o tipo do ms de `long` para `long long` e mesmo assim obtive o erro.

### Funcionou com essa estrutura

```
#include <sys/time.h>

long long getTime(){
  struct timeval tp;
  gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
  long long sec = tp.tv_sec;
  long long msec = tp.tv_usec;     
  sec *= 1000;        
  msec /= 1000;
  long long ms = sec + msec;
  return ms;
}
```